# Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password-opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart

I have problem in my code,when i am successfully registered and click on continue then it goes to login form.I'm enter my "email" and "password" then it gives me error like

> "Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password."

Below is my login.tpl code

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?>    </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo  $entry_email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-password"><?php echo $entry_password; ?></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_password; ?>" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
        <a href="<?php echo $forgotten; ?>"><?php echo $text_forgotten; ?></a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_login; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <?php if ($redirect) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

After registration i go to admin panel:customer then i click on edit and there again i put password and confirm and save it after that i logged in to my account .How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

check your admin panel first that is the customer is registered or not. If customer is not registered then check your error log for errors. you must be having issue in your controller or model. The issue can also be occur if you are using any third party modules based on Vqmod or OCmod.

Go to Opencart admin panel: System > tools > Error Logs

Clear your error log then do the same registration process and then check for errors or you can share it her with me.

Comment: this is what we need to look into... Please share your error log!